# Xen USB pass through

Tags: linux, xen, usb

Running the Xen (Debian). I want to access the iKey USB dongle from Windows DomU. I have 2 PCI:

lspci:
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)

After using Pciback, I am able to Pass the USB to Guest.

DomU.log:
register_real_device: Real physical device 00:14.0 registered successfuly!
register_real_device: Real physical device 00:1a.0 registered successfuly!

In the machine, USB and USB-SS Ports are available. But even after installing Xen drivers, in the DomU, I can see only 1a.0 and Not 14.0. When I start DomU, getting the following error for 14.a:
The kernel doesn't support reset from sysfs for PCI device..

Any tips??

Answer (score 0):

It may be (and may be not) related to the Xen toolstack in Dom0. I recently experimented with passing a PCI card and a USB controller to HVM DomU, and had completely different experience depending on tools used.

1. With pure XM/Xend and Xen 4.2, I was able to pass the USB controller only, but unable to bind the PCI card, even together with its parent PCI bridge.
2. Using XL to create DomU in a XM/Xend environment with Xen 4.2, allowed me to pass both devices (although error messages were displayed almost each time), but the option-ROM was not executed, although the card was then usable by Windows.
3. Upgrading to pure XL and Xen 4.3, finally helped to recognize the option-ROM, but the card always rebooted the DomU upon keypress.

So you may want to try different Xen versions and toolstacks.

As for the USB controller type, are you sure that both devices are true hosts that can be used to attach peripherals? (I'm not an expert in this, but I noticed that USB infrastructure usually consists of several layers, some of which are supplementary.) Moreover, xHCI may stand for USB 3.0, so are you sure that your Windows version supports USB 3.0, especially in a virtualized environment?